# Count the number of Sick Days (Denoted by "S") for each employee

Tags: excel, formula, countif

so I have created a leaver tracker for our employees in an excel file.
**Background:** Each sheet represents each month (ie: Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.) which includes the following information:
 [image: Snipping of October Sheet]

** Note: This file is a template I downloaded from Google.

I have created another sheet which outlines the following: [image: Sample Summary Table] **Note:** these are sample data.

**Question**: What formula can I use to count the number of Sick Days (S), Annual Leavel (H) and Half Days (HA) separately for all 12 months across all sheets with 1 formula?

Comment: You have to use `Countf()` formula 12 times for 12 sheets and then sum those result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you can do this:

- Without macro

  - Write a first sum formula in each sheet (after the last day)
  - In your Dashboard, write a sum formula from the previous sheet formula

or:

- Write a marco to do it